# How to import multiple python scripts in one script tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, toolbox

ESRI gives the option to import a script directly into a tool in your toolbox, eliminating the need for managing both the toolbox and the python script it refers to.

[image: When you press the right mouse button on a script tool in a toolbox]

I have a script tool that refers to one script, but that script uses another script (stored in the same folder). I would like to import both scripts into the tool, so that I only have to manage the toolbox. ESRI only offers the option to import one script.

How can I import both (or multiple for someone else his/her case) scripts into one tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot import multiple scripts. The script tools have been originally designed to be based on a single Python without considering users writing multimodular Python tools.

The [option to zip the modules with the `__main__.py` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152545/3346915) doesn't work as script tool would not understand the .zip file as its source.

Running the Python scripts outside of ArcMap first [producing the compiled `.pyc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065915/hide-protect-python-code) files and then using them for the source of the script tool doesn't work either.

Your best bet is to refactor your tool into a single file using some 3rd party tools such [Breeder](https://github.com/pagekite/PyBreeder) or manually.

If you have a large tool with many modules and don't want to refactor them into a single file and you do care about the intellectual property protection, [write custom GP tools using ArcObjects and C# / Java](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#8ecb25e7-dccb-41be-bf81-10af146e31c0.htm) or [Python extensions with C that would work with `arcpy`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/calling-a-dll-from-a-script-tool.htm) (I'd pick this one).

Comment: Thanks. I'll just manually create one script, since it is roughly 200 lines of code it should not be too dificult.

Comment: One question to ask yourself is whether or not you truly need to import your scripts.  See my response in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242482/packaging-third-party-libraries-with-python-toolbox-of-arcpy/242486#242486) for an example folder structure that you could just as easily distribute.